# How can I avoid `pip install -e` doing work when it's not necessary?

Tags: pip

I've got some directories with unknown contents beyond the fact that each has a `pyproject.toml` in it. My build system is recognising these as Python projects and installing them with `pip install -e` into the existing virtual environment.

However, this need be done only once. Yet, if I run the same `pip install -e` command again, it does a lot of work and takes a long time. How can I avoid re-doing this work, while still making sure that the project is installed if it has not yet been?

Note that I don't know what's in these packages or even their names (which may not be the same as the directory name); I'm simply checking a list of directories to see which ones have a `pyproject.toml` in them.